# Cant set Limit values in query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am using Codeigniter i am facing an issue while setting the values of "Limit" in a query,Limit is only showing "limit NULL"

Here is the snippet of my code.

```
SELECT block.loc, owner.name , block.dist_name FROM   house INNER JOIN block ON house.block_id = block.block_id INNER JOIN owner ON owner.house_id = house.house_id WHERE 
            block.dist = ? AND house.status = 5 limit ? , ? 
 $result = $this->db->query($qry, array($this->getDist(), (int) $this->getLimitStart(), (int) $this->getLimitOffset()));
```

dump for

```
(int) $this->getLimitStart() is '0' and (int) $this->getLimitOffset() is '10'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand that you make your own getter setter of the object, the getter which u are providing in you query, is returning NULL is only because you are not using the same setter.

For Example:
  if You use it ($this->getLimitOffset()) you have to set it also like this yourObject->setLimitOffset(10). I think it will work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

You should swap the start and offset values like this

```
SELECT block.loc, owner.name , block.dist_name FROM   house INNER JOIN block ON house.block_id = block.block_id INNER JOIN owner ON owner.house_id = house.house_id WHERE 
        block.dist = ? AND house.status = 5 limit ? , ? 
 $result = $this->db->query($qry, array($this->getDist(), (int) $this->getLimitOffset(),(int) $this->getLimitStart()));
```

Becsuse codeigniter active record limit's first parameter is limit abd second is offset.

```
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html
```

Comment: Well TBH swapping didnt anything altough it wa quite visible that both return numeric values, and using them in swapped order didnt make any sense still i tried and it didnt helped.

Comment: Well $this->db->limit(10,20); means limit is 10 and starting point is 20 but here you are providing limit 0 so it won't give you any result. Change it to $this->db->limit(10,10);

Comment: $this->db->limit(10,10); i have tried this.Didnt work, Further if we use $this->db->limit(10,10) or pass limit as parameter in both way it would work but the thing is that instead of "0" or "10" it is returning me "Null"

Comment: Sorry try this because it is possible that the query will not fetch more then 10 results $this->db->limit(10,0);

Comment: Man what u are not getting is that when i set limit it actually donot set it rather it returns "Null"

Comment: OK then instead of using query binding use something else because i think query binding may work with where condition but not with limit , order by and group by etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$this->db->limit($nrecords, $offset);`

Comment: Can you document in your answer how this solves the problem? Thanks!